# joomla subquery Declaration

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

DEar Friends i need help on declaring this query in joomla

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.tire_id,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.width ORDER BY a.width) AS width, 
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.aspectratio ORDER BY a.aspectratio) AS aspectratio,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.radialbias ORDER BY a.radialbias) AS radialbias,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ring ORDER BY a.ring) AS ring
                        FROM  ofhmc_nikran_tire_detail a
                        WHERE %s
                    group  by a.tire_id ) b
                    inner join ofhmc_nikran_tire c on b.tire_id = c.id
                    where %s"
```

i coded this :

```
// Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();        
    // Create a new query object.
    // $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $tiretype_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($tiretype as $value) {
        $tiretype_Query .= "c.cat_id LIKE '%.$value.%' OR ";
        # code...
    }
    $tiretype_Query = ($tiretype_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($tiretype_Query,0,strlen($tiretype_Query)-3).') ';

    $tirewidth_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($tirewidth as $value) {
        $tirewidth_Query .= 'a.width LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $tirewidth_Query = ($tirewidth_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($tirewidth_Query,0,strlen($tirewidth_Query)-3).') ';

    $aspectratio_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($aspectratio as $value) {
        $aspectratio_Query .= ' a.aspectratio LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $aspectratio_Query = ($aspectratio_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($aspectratio_Query,0,strlen($aspectratio_Query)-3).') ';

    $radialbias_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($radialbias as $value) {
        $radialbias_Query .= ' a.radialbias LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $radialbias_Query = ($radialbias_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($radialbias_Query,0,strlen($radialbias_Query)-3).') ';

    $ring_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($ring as $value) {
        $ring_Query .= ' a.ring LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $ring_Query = ($ring_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($ring_Query,0,strlen($ring_Query)-3).') ';

    $pattern_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($pattern as $value) {
        $pattern_Query .= ' c.pattern LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $pattern_Query = ($pattern_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($pattern_Query,0,strlen($pattern_Query)-3).') ';

    $corrector = " 1 = 1 ";

    $ConcatQueryDetail = $corrector .' '.$tirewidth_Query.$aspectratio_Query.$radialbias_Query.$ring_Query;
    $ConcatQueryMaster = $corrector .' '.$tiretype_Query.$pattern_Query;

    $sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.tire_id,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.width ORDER BY a.width) AS width, 
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.aspectratio ORDER BY a.aspectratio) AS aspectratio,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.radialbias ORDER BY a.radialbias) AS radialbias,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ring ORDER BY a.ring) AS ring
                        FROM  ofhmc_nikran_tire_detail a
                        WHERE %s
                    group  by a.tire_id ) b
                    inner join ofhmc_nikran_tire c on b.tire_id = c.id
                    where %s",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($ConcatQueryDetail),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($ConcatQueryMaster));
    // $sql = str_replace("\", "", $sql);
    return($sql);
    // $db->setQuery($sql);
    // $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    // return $results;
```

but i still face with problem because joomla retrieve \ whith in \'%'.$value.'%\' and it makes my query wrong 
plz help me on this

i'm looking for a way to implement this query with jDatabaseClass
THank YOU

Comment: why not just do " c.pattern LIKE '%".$value."%' OR ". Also i advise using sql parameters (have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Help me:

```
$sql = str_replace("\\", "", $sql);
```

entire source is:

```
public function getTires2($tiretype,$tirewidth,$aspectratio,$radialbias,$ring,$pattern)
{
    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();        
    // Create a new query object.
    //$query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $tiretype_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($tiretype as $value) {
        $tiretype_Query .= 'c.cat_id LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $tiretype_Query = ($tiretype_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($tiretype_Query,0,strlen($tiretype_Query)-3).') ';

    $tirewidth_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($tirewidth as $value) {
        $tirewidth_Query .= 'a.width LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $tirewidth_Query = ($tirewidth_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($tirewidth_Query,0,strlen($tirewidth_Query)-3).') ';

    $aspectratio_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($aspectratio as $value) {
        $aspectratio_Query .= ' a.aspectratio LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $aspectratio_Query = ($aspectratio_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($aspectratio_Query,0,strlen($aspectratio_Query)-3).') ';

    $radialbias_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($radialbias as $value) {
        $radialbias_Query .= ' a.radialbias LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $radialbias_Query = ($radialbias_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($radialbias_Query,0,strlen($radialbias_Query)-3).') ';

    $ring_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($ring as $value) {
        $ring_Query .= ' a.ring LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $ring_Query = ($ring_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($ring_Query,0,strlen($ring_Query)-3).') ';

    $pattern_Query = 'AND (';
    foreach ($pattern as $value) {
        $pattern_Query .= ' c.pattern LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\' OR ';
        # code...
    }
    $pattern_Query = ($pattern_Query == 'AND (')?'':substr($pattern_Query,0,strlen($pattern_Query)-3).') ';

    $corrector = " 1 = 1 ";

    $ConcatQueryDetail = $corrector .' '.$tirewidth_Query.$aspectratio_Query.$radialbias_Query.$ring_Query;
    $ConcatQueryMaster = $corrector .' '.$tiretype_Query.$pattern_Query;

    $sql=sprintf('SELECT f.title,d.* FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.tire_id,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.width ORDER BY a.width) AS width, 
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.aspectratio ORDER BY a.aspectratio) AS aspectratio,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.radialbias ORDER BY a.radialbias) AS radialbias,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ring ORDER BY a.ring) AS ring
                        FROM  #__nikran_tire_detail a
                        WHERE %s
                    group  by a.tire_id ) b
                    inner join #__nikran_tire c on b.tire_id = c.id
                    where %s )d
                    inner join #__categories f on f.id= d.cat_id' ,
                    mysql_real_escape_string($ConcatQueryDetail),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($ConcatQueryMaster));
    $sql = str_replace("\\", "", $sql);
    // return($sql);
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $results;

}
```